# Can I use regasm to register a .Net COM as SingleUse

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, regasm

Can I register a .Net COM class with the [SingleUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationconnectiontype%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-flag?

The reason I want to use SingleUse is that otherwise the static fields inside the COM instances (the client application uses 2 instances with different database connection strings) are shared resulting in any COM instance to access the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't go in the registry.  It is a property of an out-of-process COM server, used when it registers its class factories.  The dwClsContext argument for [CoRegisterClassObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Using static fields is your mistake.  Easy to fix.

Comment: thanks, well not my mistake (old inherited codebase) and yes easy to fix, but time consuming, I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss any other alternatives...

Comment: You didn't.  You know what to do.